# Scope variable not binding in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

one of my within scope variables is remaining at 'all'. I am console logging to check if I get the right value and it comes out to ,Steps, Walkthrough, Ref when I select different options, but the type variable remains at all as if I'm not actually changing it with the last line.

here is my html:

```
<div class="inputs">
    <select class="filters">
        <option ng-model="type" name="Steps" value="all">All<br/>
        <option ng-model="type" name="Steps" value="Steps">Steps<br/>
        <option ng-model="type" name="Steps" value="Walkthrough">Walkthrough<br/>
        <option ng-model="type" name="Steps" value="Ref">Ref<br/>
    </select>
    {{type}}
</div>
```

And Controller:

```
$('.filters').change(function() {
    console.log($('option:selected', this).attr('value'));
    $scope.type = $('option:selected', this).attr('value');
});
```

Attached is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jTu93/), but I don't think I got the libraries right or something. in the fiddle where It shows {{type}} as the ouput, that is actually 'all' and never changes. 
Thanks so much

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jTu93/1/)

Comment: Your fiddle isn't setup right, http://jsfiddle.net/jTu93/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to mix jQuery with AngularJS:

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bB55B/)

```
<div ng-app="MdApp">
    <div ng-controller="MdCtrl">
        <select class="filters" ng-model="type">
         <option ng-model="type" name="Steps" value="all">All</option>
            <option ng-model="type" name="Steps" value="Steps">Steps</option>
            <option ng-model="type" name="Steps" value="Walkthrough">Walkthrough</option>
            <option ng-model="type" name="Steps" value="Ref">Ref</option>
        </select>
        {{type}}
    </div>
</div>  

var app = angular.module('MdApp',[]);
function MdCtrl($scope, $attrs) {

    $scope.type = 'all';


}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know why his jquery change event doesn't fire? I can't really explain it.

Comment: Using Jquery inside the controller is considered as bad practice in Angular JS. That all I know :)

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll watch out when mixing the both of them!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<div ng-app="MdApp">
    <div ng-controller="MdCtrl">
        <select class="filters" ng-model="type">
         <option ng-model="type" name="Steps" value="all">All</option>
            <option ng-model="type" name="Steps" value="Steps">Steps</option>
            <option ng-model="type" name="Steps" value="Walkthrough">Walkthrough</option>
            <option ng-model="type" name="Steps" value="Ref">Ref</option>
        </select>
        {{type}}
    </div>
</div> 


var app = angular.module('MdApp',[])
    .controller('MdCtrl', function($scope, $attrs) {

    $scope.type = 'all';
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7XqJ/)